Python pandas iteration
Code:
# Import cars data
import pandas as pd
cars = pd.read_csv('cars.csv', index_col = 0)
# Adapt for loop
for lab, row in cars.iterrows() :
    print(f"{[lab]}: {row['cars_per_cap']}")

Output:
['US']: 809
['AUS']: 731
['JPN']: 588
['IN']: 18
['RU']: 200
['MOR']: 70
['EG']: 45

The output I'm getting is fine but how can I remove brackets and the commas around the country names pls help I ayone knows.
I tried the doubling the brackets around the 'lab' but it did'nt worked.

You don't need to put the Lab inside [].
So it will look something like this:
# Import cars data
import pandas as pd
cars = pd.read_csv('cars.csv', index_col=0)

# Adapt for loop
for lab, row in cars.iterrows():
    # Directly use lab without brackets and quotes
    print(f"{lab}: {row['cars_per_cap']}")
 

